# Как подобрать плагин для Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Подскажите плагин, который сможет выводить последние товары в ряд в виде слайдера и при нажатии на нужный товар попадали на него.

Answer (score 2):

Я когда-то использовал вот [такую](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tiny-carousel-horizontal-slider-plus/) карусель, но сейчас использую js-плагины типа слайдер кит и подключаю все через `get_categories();`. Сама же карусель геморройная, хотя если не знаете кода, выручит.